# scanf() function doesn't work?

Tags: c

This may be a simple question, but i searched a lot and still didn't figure it out. 
I compiles below snip code by gcc and run program from terminal. In correct, It allow to enter an int and a char but it doesn't. It doesn't wait to enter the char??

Anyone here can help me will be kind. thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  char c;
  int i;

  // a
  printf("i: ");
  fflush(stdin); scanf("%d", &i);

  // b
  printf("c: ");
  fflush(stdin); scanf("%c", &c);

  return 0;
```

}

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` gives you undefined behavior, don't do it.

Comment: Did you give it an enter key as well as the input?

Comment: fflush is not defined on the input stream. Too bad some C books actually encourage it.

Comment: What does it give?  The code snippet ends with scanf(), so nothing is being done with the variable `c`.  Actually, the same for `i`.  Note that scanf() parsing depends a lot on the `stty` settings of the terminal, if the input is a terminal.

Answer (score 8):

`%d` will read consecutive digits until it encounters a non-digit. `%c` reads one character. Probably what's happening is that you're giving it a number (several digits) followed by a new line. `%c` then reads in that new line. You were probably intending for the `fflush(stdin);` to discard anything that hadn't yet been read, but unfortunately, [that's undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209).

The solution is to discard all whitespace before reading the character:

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

Note the space at the start. That means to discard all whitespace.

Comment: It is exactly what I did: enter a number and followed by a new line. It works now! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getchar()` to achieve what you want.

or consume the extra newline by using:-

```
 scanf(" %c", &c);
  ^^^   <------------Note the space
```

Reason:- Your next scanf for reading the character just reads/consumes the newline and hence never waits for user input

Comment: Replacing `scanf("%c", &c);` with `c = getchar();` shows the same behavior for me.

Comment: I know, but I want to figure out how it doesn't work in this case. Futher more, when I changes the order //a and //b then it works.

Comment: Your next scanf for reading the character just reads/consumes the newline and hence never waits for user input

Comment: @dangnam2910: updated my answer with the reason. Hope that makes it clear!!!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `fflush(stdin); scanf("%c", &c);`

1.use scanf with extra space

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

or

2.use getchar() two times , first time reads '\n' which is entered after giving integer input and second time call ask you for give input as `c:`

```
getchar();
c=getchar();
```

would help you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `scanf` works when used as directed.  I think the following code does what you want.  Stdout is flushed so that user is prompted to enter an integer or a character.  Using %1s allows white space like \n.

```
int main()
{

  char c[2];
  int i;

  printf("i: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%d", &i);

  printf("c: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%1s", &c);

  printf("\ni = %d, c = %c", i, c[0]);

  return 0;

}
```

This code was tested/run on an Eclipse/Microsoft C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

That fflush() is not guaranteed to do anything, and gcc/g++ doesn't.  Not on Linux, anyway.

I thought I invented the following way to flush the rest of a line...until I saw it as an example in the ISO C spec (90 or 99...forgot which, but it's been there a long time either way...and I'll bet most readers here have seen it before.)

`scanf("%*[^\n]%*c"); /* discard everything up to and including the next newline */`

You can put that in your own "flush" function to save typing or pasting that all over the place.

You should still follow the suggestions to to put a space in `scanf(" %c", &c);`.

That will patiently wait for a non-whitespace character in case of a leading space or a double hit of the enter key.