# Following C code is not working

Tags: c

I don't understand why it's taking only first input

Code is :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _book
{
    char title[100];
    char author[50];
    char genre[30];
}
books;


// function to get title from user
void get_title(books *b)
{
    printf("Enter the title of the book: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", b->title);
}

// function to get author from user
void get_author(books *b)
{
    printf("Enter name of the author: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", b->author);
}

// function to get genre from user
void get_genre(books *b)
{
    printf("Enter the genre of the book: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", b->genre);
}

// function to display book title
void print_title(books b)
{
    printf("Title of the book is: %s\n", b.title);
}

// function to display book author
void print_author(books b)
{
    printf("Author of the book is: %s\n", b.author);
}

// function to display book genre
void print_genre(books b)
{
    printf("Genre of the book is: %s\n", b.genre);
}


int main()
{
    // defining book variable
    books book;

    // getting inputs from user
    get_title(&book);
    get_author(&book);
    get_genre(&book);


    // displaying outputs
    printf("Details of the book :-\n");
    print_title(book);
    print_author(book);
    print_genre(book);
}
```

It is taking only first input then displaying everything without waiting for user input.  You can see the output image in the link given below

Here you can see output :-

[image: output]

Comment: The problem is incorrect use of `scanf()`, with the format strings you provide, `scanf()` can never read a newline. See also [a beginners' guide away from scanf](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) (disclaimer: my doc...)

Comment: With such big struct i would pass pointers to it in print functions. What you are doing is copying whole struct onto stack.

Comment: Names starting with underscore are reserved for the implementation in file-scope for all name-spaces. This includes the `struct` name-space. **Do not use them in your code**

Comment: And don't post images of text!

Comment: The output is plain text, not graphical artwork. Please include it as text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _book
{
    char title[100];
    char author[50];
    char genre[30];
}
books;


// function to get title from user
void get_title(books *b)
{
    printf("Enter the title of the book: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", b->title);
}

// function to get author from user
void get_author(books *b)
{
    printf("Enter name of the author: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", b->author);
}

// function to get genre from user
void get_genre(books *b)
{
    printf("Enter the genre of the book: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", b->genre);
}

// function to display book title
void print_title(books b)
{
    printf("Title of the book is: %s\n", b.title);
}

// function to display book author
void print_author(books b)
{
    printf("Author of the book is: %s\n", b.author);
}

// function to display book genre
void print_genre(books b)
{
    printf("Genre of the book is: %s\n", b.genre);
}


int main()
{
    // defining book variable
    books book;

    // getting inputs from user
    get_title(&book);
    get_author(&book);
    get_genre(&book);


    // displaying outputs
    printf("Details of the book :-\n");
    print_title(book);
    print_author(book);
    print_genre(book);
}
```

Comment: Correct, but a *really* good answer should explain why ... Maybe you want to add some explanation, ideally also concerning the *buffer overflow* that's still possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425307/scanf-function-doesnt-work

Comment: Yup! Got it
Thanks